# How to unit test Asp.net core WebAPI (net452) project?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

I currently have a Asp.net Core Web.Api project.
It (only) **targets the net452** framework. 
Question is: How do I unit test an asp,net core WebAPI (net452) project?

I already tried adding a classic .net unit testing project to my solution, with a reference to my web.api core project.
For some reason, I'm not able to declare (refer) any class inside my webapi project.
From this, I conclude, I cannot use a classic unit testing project to test my Asp.net core project.

inside my project.json:

```
 "frameworks": {
   "net452": {}
   }
}
```

this is how my solution looks like:

[image: solution]

inside my test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class ActiveDirectoryClientProviderTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Get_Should_Return_Client()
    {
        //var settings = new ActiveDirectorySettings();
        Ng2Aa_demo.Domain.Avatar.GetAvatarByUserHandler
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use xUnit or NUnit, both works well with .Net core.

Here is a tutorial on how to create the unit test project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test

You basically create a .Net core class library, import the xUnit or NUnit library and set the unit test runner.

An example of a project json using xUnit:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type":"platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "xunit":"2.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-192208-24",
    "PrimeService": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/docs/master/samples/core/getting-started/unit-testing-using-dotnet-test/test/PrimeService.Tests/project.json)

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to add another core project
   [image]
2. Inside your project.json 
   add 2 dependencies & specify the testRunner. **Make sure to use Xunit** !!

[image]

```
"xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
"dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
```

**Now you can unit test your web api core project with xunit !**